# Removing objects from an array using a for loop

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I found some code similar to this  (not exactly just the weird logic has been replicated) :

```
for(int counter = 0 ; counter < array.length() ; counter ++ ) {
    array.removeObjectAtIndex(i);
    counter -- ;
}
```

Is this bad code ? What should one do assuming there is no primitive method to empty the whole array or that we need to do some extra cleanup after removing each element ?

Comment: What does `counter --;` do?

Comment: otherwise all the elements wouldnt get removed . And whoever downvoted this know that this has been found in production code !

Comment: What is i defined to be?  Is it set to zero?  I would suggest you write a subroutine to do the remove object.  There are several ways it can be done, but I don't think I would have written it as you have it there.

Comment: @eddardstark Production code doesn't mean that the code is good.

Comment: Your code snippet is incomplete and it looks more like C++ than C. Claiming that `counter--` is needed to remove all elements just does not compute.

Comment: i dont know why i'm getting downvoted . I know this is wrong. And contrary to what HonkyTonk is saying counter -- is definitely needed in this wtf approach . I know a few ways of doing this I just wanted to see what others would suggest . There are two ways going top down and repeatedly removing the first element .

Comment: @eddardstark thought you got your head chopped off? my bad. :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you go from the top down, you won't need `counter--`, and it's more efficient because it won't have to shift the array elements above each time `removeObjectAtIndex` is called.

Comment: +1 for efficiency . I think your approach is better than the other answer.

Comment: Agreed absolutely, though we have no idea what `array` is or how removal is implemented. e.g. no inefficiency if it's a linked list implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Interfering with a loop counter inside the loop body is never a good idea.

Despite not knowing what `array` is, a better way would be to continuously remove the array head until the array is empty.

```
int length = array.length();
for(int counter = 0 ; counter < length ; counter++ )
{
    array.removeObjectAtIndex(0);
}
```

Comment: Untrue. There are situations when you can decide inside the for loop you want to skip the next 5 elements or maybe you're implementing something that requires you to look ahead/back and then shift the current index.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first thing to note here is that at the end of every loop there's a `counter++` and a `counter--`. Effectively canceling each other out.

I suspect a junior programmer was taught that for loops **require** the format

```
for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {/*code*/}
```

Going forth on that logic, due to the length for the array shifting by one with each pass in the loop, he required counter to get decremented as well (as to not generate fake results).

```
for(int c=0;c<a.length();c++){a.remove(i);c--;}
```

If you remove `c--` from this implementation, you would remove only half the indexes. Counter would go up as length would go down, effectively meeting half way.

Now a different implementation that feels less rigid

```
for(;array.length()>0;){array.removeObjectAtIndex(i);}
// also this
for(;array.length();array.removeObjectAtIndex(i));
```

---

OP mentioned `.length()` might be inefficient, so:

```
for(int len=array.length();len--;array.removeObjectAtIndex(i));
```

For's are incredibly powerful, I personally find them highly underused in some situations.

Comment: this one i had not thought of ! but repeatedly computing length is a bit inefficient no ?

Comment: Yes... and no... it highly depends on what it is you are trying to achieve. Considering this very specific situation, yes. I was just trying to reverse engineer how the code got to look like that. Especially the counter++/-- is baffling to me. `for(int l=a.length();l;l--,a.removeAtIndex(i));` is also valid and buffers length. It really depends on what remove does... maybe it removes more than one node. I don't know...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with acraig5075's comment  about interfering  with a loop counter inside the loop body is bad habbit

i think bottom up approach as below code will work fine

```
for(int counter = array.length - 1; counter >= 0; counter--)
{
      array.removeObjectAtIndex(counter);
}
```